# Best way to associate records on different tables with SQLite

Tags: php, database, sqlite, optimization

I'm developing an open source download manager in PHP, it's my first time dealing with databases and I wanted to know what is the best (optimized) way to retrieve multiple records from two tables as follows:

Table A is the main list of downloads, each one has an 'id'.
Table B has ranges for connections used  for each download in the previous table. Having 'start', 'end', 'bytes' and 'downloadid'. Each download has one or more ranges associated using 'downloadid'.

I simply want to retrieve the list of downloads and its ranges in the most optimized way.

Answer (score 1):

select a.id, a.col1, a.col2, b.col1, b.col2 from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.id = b.dataloadid where a.id = <reqid> order by b.start

You should of course replace the <reqid> with the dataloadid you're looking for.
Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: i just don't understand the "where" part :)

Comment: I think you can get rid of the "where a.id =" part as I don't see anywhere where you set up constraints. You didn't say a specific criteria on which you were looking against so that would give you a joined list of all downloads. It would be more useful if we had some test inputs/intended outputs here, but if you were wanting the ID from tableA and all of the details for tableB, it might be better to just say select downloadid as ID, start, end, bytes from tableB. I'm assuming there are more details in tableA than given, but just wanted to put that out there.

Comment: After looking at this again, I'd say you do need a join (you don't outline contents of TableA, but imply there is other data). I'm not sure what your "where" clause would be as you don't lay out any conditions. Perhaps there is a UserID field in TableA (that links back to a Users table) so you would do "where userid = 1" to select all downloads that the person with userid of 1 has performed. If start/end are datetime values, you might exclude items that happened before a certain time. As written, it is vague what the conditions are. http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html may help in general.